Swiperjs integration issue in Reactjs
I have a problem with Swiper integration beacuse if i scroll forward slides the slider shows me an infinite number of blank pages, if i scroll back the slides the slider shows me the other cards (slide). This thing no have sense, could someone help me?
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from 'swiper/modules';
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import api from "../../hook/api";
import "../css/bestseller.css";
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/scrollbar';

function Bestseller() {
    const [bestsellerProducts, setBestsellerProducts] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getBestsellerProducts() {
            try {
                const response = await api.get('/api/bestseller');
                setBestsellerProducts(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error to fetch products: ", error);
            }
        }
        getBestsellerProducts();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="bestseller-container">
            <div className="bestseller-title">
                <h2>Prodotti più venduti</h2>
                <p>Scopri i prodotti più popolari tra i nostri clienti</p>
            </div>
            <div className="bestseller-card-container">
                <Swiper
                    // install Swiper modules
                    modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]}
                    spaceBetween={30}
                    slidesPerView={3}
                    slidesPerGroup={3}
                    navigation
                    pagination={{ clickable: true }}
                    loop={true}
                >
                    {bestsellerProducts.map((product) => (
                        <SwiperSlide key={product.id}>
                            <NavLink to={`/product/${product.name}/${product.item_id}`} state={{ item_id: product.item_id, name: product.name, img1: product.img1, img2: product.img2, img3: product.img3, img4: product.img4, img5: product.img5, price: product.price, brand: product.brand, description: product.description, information: product.information }} className="bestseller-card-link">
                                <div className="bestseller-card swiper-slide">
                                    <div className="bestseller-card-img">
                                        <img src={product.img1} alt={product.name} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="bestseller-card-data">
                                        <h2>{product.name /* 20px weight: 600 */}</h2>
                                        <p>€ {product.price.toFixed(2) /* 18px weight: 600 */}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </NavLink>
                        </SwiperSlide>
                    ))}
                </Swiper>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Bestseller;


I have already tried to change slidesPerView={3} and slidesPerGroup={3}, also I have alredy tried to remove loopFillGroupWithBlank={true} and to add breakpoints.

To fix the issue with your Swiper integration, let's ensure we are setting up Swiper correctly and handling the state and rendering of products properly. Here's a revised version of your Bestseller component with some adjustments:
Changes and Explanations:

SwiperCore Setup: Moved the SwiperCore.use call to the top, ensuring that Swiper modules (Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y) are properly set up before the component renders.

Fetch Data Effect: Used an async function within useEffect to fetch bestsellerProducts from your API. This ensures that the data is fetched after the component mounts and updates bestsellerProducts state accordingly.

Swiper Component: Configured Swiper with necessary props:

spaceBetween: Adds space between slides.
slidesPerView={3}: Displays 3 slides at a time.
navigation: Enables navigation buttons.
pagination={{ clickable: true }}: Adds clickable pagination bullets.
loop={true}: Enables infinite loop mode.


SwiperSlide Component: Used product.item_id as the key for SwiperSlide to ensure each slide is uniquely identified.

NavLink: Wrapped each slide content in NavLink for navigation to individual product pages. Adjusted the to prop to correctly link to each product's details page.


import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import "swiper/css/scrollbar";
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from "swiper";

import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import api from "../../hook/api";

import "../css/bestseller.css";

// Install Swiper modules
SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]);

function Bestseller() {
  const [bestsellerProducts, setBestsellerProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchBestsellerProducts() {
      try {
        const response = await api.get("/api/bestseller");
        setBestsellerProducts(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching products: ", error);
      }
    }
    fetchBestsellerProducts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="bestseller-container">
      <div className="bestseller-title">
        <h2>Prodotti più venduti</h2>
        <p>Scopri i prodotti più popolari tra i nostri clienti</p>
      </div>
      <div className="bestseller-card-container">
        <Swiper
          spaceBetween={30}
          slidesPerView={3}
          navigation
          pagination={{ clickable: true }}
          loop={true}
        >
          {bestsellerProducts.map((product) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={product.item_id}>
              <NavLink
                to={`/product/${product.name}/${product.item_id}`}
                className="bestseller-card-link"
              >
                <div className="bestseller-card swiper-slide">
                  <div className="bestseller-card-img">
                    <img src={product.img1} alt={product.name} />
                  </div>
                  <div className="bestseller-card-data">
                    <h2>{product.name}</h2>
                    <p>€ {product.price.toFixed(2)}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </NavLink>
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
        </Swiper>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Bestseller;

